# System Locale in .NET

Tags: c#, locale, culture

I have set the system locale to Chinese (Simplified PRC) via

```
ControlPanel >> Region and Language >> Administrative >> Change System locale
```

I then restarted my computer and run my .NET 4.0 application.

Running

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Name
```

Returns

```
en-GB
```

Why?

Comment: try: Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.Name  (notice the UI)

Comment: I get the same behavior with `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.Name `

Answer (score 2):

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.clearcacheddata.aspx) says that

> Information, such as the default culture and format patterns, is
>   cached the first time it is requested. That information can change
>   during the life of the AppDomain, for example, when the user modifies
>   the regional and language options portion of Control Panel. However,
>   the CultureInfo class does not automatically detect changes in the
>   system settings.

call this first

```
 Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.ClearCachedData();
```

Comment: I can get `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Name` to return the expected value by setting `Region and Language >> Formats` to `Chinese (SImplified PRC)`. Is this expected behavior? The culture exposed in .NET seems to be only affected by this "Format" setting.

Comment: @Ben i didn't get your question

Comment: Changing `ControlPanel >> Region and Language >> Administrative >> Change System locale` does not seem to change the value exposed in `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Name`. Instead, according to my experiments, setting `Control Panel >> Region and Language >> Formats` does. Is this per your understanding. I presumed setting the "Locale" in the control panel would set the locale in .NET.

Comment: i will have to check what change System Local does. Though MSDN does say that changing default format affects the culture

Answer (score -1):

Looks like the place to see the system locale is System.Text.Encoding.Default

PS: The "...Change system locale" affects the ANSI codepage used for "non-Unicode" applications (the *A() calls from Win32 API). In most cases .NET applications do not need to care about it because they use Unicode strings and Unicode API. But I have to interact with non-unicode application, so I need to inquire the current system locale.

Comment: I think that must be wrong. I see nothing relevant to culture, just encodings.

Comment: "System locale" is not much relevant to culture, however de understand it, as well, it is "just encoding"